# Form com PHP envia variáveis POST para mesma página com jQuery sem recarregar

Tags: php, jquery, post

Este código básico abaixo será usado para filtrar via POST E jQuery um `SELECT` em uma página PHP.

O form envia para a mesma página, o jQuery recebe e envia para o PHP, que recebe via `$_POST["campanha"];`.

A página não deveria estar dando *refresh* mas isso está acontecendo. Alguém pode me ajudar com esse erro, por gentileza?

```html
<html> 
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
           $("#bot_enviar").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
               var varCampanha = $("#campanha").val();
               $.post('teste.php', {
                   type:"POST",
                   campanha: varCampanha
               }, function(response){
                    alert(campanha);
               });
           });
        })
    </script>
</head> 
<body>

<form action="" method="post" id="bot_enviar">
    <select name="campanha" name="campanha">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
<br>

<input type="submit" >
</form>



Campanha: <?php echo $_POST["campanha"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Há alguns erros no seu código. O seu `<input type="submit" >` é o botão que envia e recarrega a página. Você não colocou o evento `click` nesse botão, e sim colocou-o no form. Note que você colocou o `id="bot_enviar"` no form ao invés de colocar no botão.

Você deveria colocar o evento `click` no botão ou então colocar o evento `submit` no form. O que não dá é colocar o evento `click` no form.

Se preferir colocar o evento `click` no botão, então tire o `id="bot_enviar"` do form e coloque-o no botão. Eu também recomendaria mudar para `<input type="button" id="bot_enviar">`.

Se preferir colocar o evento no form, deve bastar mudar o `$("#bot_enviar").click` para `$("#bot_enviar").submit`. No entanto, nesse caso eu mudaria o nome desse id para algo que claramente demonstre que trata-se do form, e não do botão.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @victor-stafusa (As alterações citadas por ele são essenciais):

Você está chamando o método `preventDefault()` sem invocar o parâmetro event no evento do click em:

```
$("#bot_enviar").click(function(){
```

O correto seria:

```
$("#bot_enviar").click(function(event){
```